# Symfony: Apache vs built-in PHP server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, webserver

From what I understand, Apache (or Nginx) has been the server of choice (as well as it being installed as part of LAMP/WAMP/MAMP packages). However, the current installation instructions for Symfony (2.6) recommend using the built-in PHP webserver.

From what I understand, this has been in active development since php 5.4 and is making continual improvements. Could someone help give some perspective on this switch from Apache->PHP webserver?

- Is to due comparable speed/efficiency/security
- Is it more to do with simplifying the Symfony setup (and therefore
  only really to be used for development servers)?

Comment: This question only had one answer submitted and it is based on fact: the statement that the built-in server in PHP is only provided for testing and "it should not be used on a public network"

Comment: Totally agree with you, this is a highly interesting question, especially for quick public demos of PHP scripts the internal server would be extremely useful! If we also add a database with local storage (SQLite etc.) it's easily possible to create a application with just 1 file. How cool is that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read the warning in documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

> It is not intended to be a full-featured web server.

they don't intend to make the tool a webserver.

I recommend nginx with php-fpm

Comment: Thanks @StefanYohansson - that decides it then! Although, I'll also take a look at your recommendation of nginx/php-fpm. Is it faster/simpler/better than Apache2? (as I'm installing it anyway from `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`)

Comment: yes, nginx/php-fpm is more faster and better. But if you use htaccess, nginx don't parse it, you need to write the rules in site conf file. this link you'll find a "comparison" http://www.theorganicagency.com/apache-vs-nginx-performance-comparison/

Comment: it's more difficult to init in nginx/php-fpm if you aren't familiar with config a server from 0, try this http://www.unixmen.com/install-lemp-server-nginx-mysql-mariadb-php-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-14-1014-0413-10/

Comment: If you want to fast Server response, I suggest using Swoole as your php server
https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/get-started-swoole